# onclick add a class & then remove class if class is something specific

Tags: javascript

so I'm quite new to JavaScript & I have no idea how to proceed with what I'm working on.

```
        <div class="site yellow jackpot crash coinflip">
            <div class="site-image-container">
                <img class="site-image" src="image.png" alt="site-image.png">
            </div>
            <p class="site-name">TEST</p>
            <a class="site-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a>
            <p class="site-amount">$0.1</p>
            <p class="site-code">CODE</p>
        </div>

        <div class="site yellow cases">
          <div class="site-image-container">
            <img class="site-image" src="image.png" alt="site-image.png">
          </div>
          <p class="site-name">TEST</p>
          <a class="site-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a>
          <p class="site-amount">$0.50</p>
          <p class="site-code">CODE</p>
        </div>

        <div class="site red roulette crash dice coinflip">
            <div class="site-image-container">
                <img class="site-image" src="image.png" alt="site-image.png">
            </div>
            <p class="site-name">TEST</p>
            <a class="site-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a>
            <p class="site-amount">$0.50</p>
            <p class="site-code">CODE</p>
        </div>


        <div class="site purple upgrade">
            <div class="site-image-container">
                <img class="site-image" src="image.png" alt="site-image.png">
            </div>
            <p class="site-name">TEST</p>
            <a class="site-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a>
            <p class="site-amount">$0.10</p>
            <p class="site-code">CODE</p>
        </div>
```

I want to add a display-none class to all divs with the class "site" & then I want to remove the display-none class again from all divs with the class "roulette" & I want to do all this with one onclick

Comment: Can you add sample code on what you wish to achieve? That would be helpful

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: It sounds like you *do* have an idea of what you want to do. Try to implement that and post the code of your attempt!

Comment: yeah, sorry, I edited it now :)

Comment: sounds a bit like x/y problem. are you just trying to have all elements with class "site" and without "roulette" `display: none` on click ?

Comment: that is exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

Select the elements you want to hide. In this example it uses the not() selector to filter out the .roulette class.

Then set the hide class on the selected elements.

```js
//select with class site, but not roulette
const elsToHide = document.querySelectorAll(".site:not(.roulette)");


//on click
//loop these elements and add class 'hide-me'
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
  Array.from(elsToHide).forEach(el=>{
    el.classList.add("hide-me");
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-me {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
        <div class="site yellow jackpot crash coinflip">
            <div class="site-image-container">
                <img class="site-image" src="image.png" alt="site-image.png">
            </div>
            <p class="site-name">TEST</p>
            <a class="site-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a>
            <p class="site-amount">$0.1</p>
            <p class="site-code">CODE</p>
        </div>

        <div class="site yellow cases">
          <div class="site-image-container">
            <img class="site-image" src="image.png" alt="site-image.png">
          </div>
          <p class="site-name">TEST</p>
          <a class="site-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a>
          <p class="site-amount">$0.50</p>
          <p class="site-code">CODE</p>
        </div>

        <div class="site red roulette crash dice coinflip">
            <p> i have roulette in my classList! </p>
            <div class="site-image-container">
                <img class="site-image" src="image.png" alt="site-image.png">
            </div>
            <p class="site-name">TEST</p>
            <a class="site-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a>
            <p class="site-amount">$0.50</p>
            <p class="site-code">CODE</p>
        </div>


        <div class="site purple upgrade">
            <div class="site-image-container">
                <img class="site-image" src="image.png" alt="site-image.png">
            </div>
            <p class="site-name">TEST</p>
            <a class="site-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a>
            <p class="site-amount">$0.10</p>
            <p class="site-code">CODE</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: I would appreciate som rep if this was a useful answer ^.^